# „Und” zwischen zwei Verben mit unterschiedlichem Kasus

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case, contractions

> Ich werde dem Chef die Unterlage durch E-Mail zuschicken und/oder telefonieren.

oder

> Ich werde dem Chef die Unterlage durch E-Mail zuschicken und/oder ihn telefonieren.

Welcher Satz stimmt und, falls beide richtig sind, welcher ist besser?

Comment: Ich hätte nicht gewusst, was Loong schreibt: Dass man telefonieren auch transitiv verwenden kann … für mich klingt der zweite Satz grundfalsch (aus syntaktisch/grammatikalischen Gründen) und der erste semantisch unzusammenhängend.

Answer (score 8):

Beide haben kleine Fehler:

1. *telefonieren* ist ein *absolutes Verb*, das kein Objekt braucht (und allerhöchstens ein *präpositionales Objekt* haben kann, so wie z.B *warten*). Man kann im Deutschen niemanden „telefonieren“, man kann *ihn* oder umgangssprachlich *ihm* *anrufen*. *Mit ihm telefonieren* ginge.
2. Ich würde *per E-Mail* sagen

Und dein Satz sollte lauten:

> Ich werde dem Chef die Unterlagen per E-Mail zuschicken oder ihn anrufen.

oder (hier ist der zweite Hauptsatz nicht verkürzt, das wäre auch richtig):

> Ich werde dem Chef die Unterlagen per E-Mail zuschicken oder ich werde ihn anrufen.

oder, wenn’s unbedingt „telefonieren“ sein soll:

> Ich werde dem Chef die Unterlagen per E-Mail zuschicken oder mit ihm telefonieren.

Es handelt sich um zwei zusammengezogene Hauptsätze, die sich das *ich werde* teilen (es ist eine unnötige Wiederholung, die weggelassen werden kann). Weiter wirkt sich das auf die Form nicht aus; die Satzglieder werden so gebildet, wie wenn sie in einem eigenen Hauptsatz stehen würden.

Comment: "dem Chef" klingt unhöflich,  ich würde eher "meinem/seinem/unserem/ihrem Chef" sagen

Comment: Im schweizerischen Deutsch kann man auch _[jemandem telefonieren](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/telefonieren#Bedeutung2)._

Comment: @Iris Wie wird es dadurch höflicher, dass er *meiner* ist? ;)

Comment: @tofro, es ist weniger objektivierend? Ich bin mir nicht sicher warum,  aber meine sprachliche Intuition sagt,  es ist so.

Comment: @Iris: Ich kann - wie tofro - nicht erkennen, welchen Einfluss die Verwendung eines Possessivpronomens anstelle eines Artikels auf den Grad der Höflichkeit hat. Nur wenn man das Wort »dem« nicht als Artikel sondern als Demonstrativpronomen interpretiert, entsteht der unhöfliche Eindruck. Diese Interpretation ist zwar möglich, aber unüblich und meist vom Sprecher nicht beabsichtigt.

Comment: @Loong: Das gilt erstaunlicherweise für viele alemannische Dialekte - z.B. auch für den schwäbischen.

Comment: @tofro Im Allgäu hab ich das noch nicht gehört … Und aus Augsburg kenn ich zu wenige.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast, ja, für mich handelt es sich in diesem Fall eindeutig um ein Demonstrativpronomen (und das klingt unhöflich). Ein Possessivpronomen lässt hier weniger interpretationsspielraum, ob es ein Artikel oder ein Demonstrativpronomen ist.

Comment: @Iris Genauso könnte man argumentieren, dass ein besitzanzeigendes Fürwort hier unhöflich wäre und implizieren könnte, "der Chef" wäre nicht sein eigener Herr. Ich glaube, du interpretierst hier eine Aussage hinein, die gar nicht im Satz steckt - Solange man nicht "der da" sagt, ist es für mich auch kein Demonstrativpronomen.  Vielleicht können wir uns drauf einigen, dass man am besten "Herr Müller" sagt ;)

Answer (score 1):

Deine Beispiele lassen sich leider nur als zwei quasi unabhängige Hauptsätze verstehen, die zufällig durch eine Konjunktion verbunden sind, und in denen Wiederholungen ausgelassen wurden. Einen direkten semantischen Zusammenhang zu erstellen ist nicht möglich, denn mann kann Unterlagen nicht telefonisch übermitteln. Ein schöneres Beispiel wäre:

> Ich werde ih**n** unterstützen. Ich werde ih**m** helfen.

Wenn diese beiden Sätze zusammengezogen werden, kann man die entstandene Verbindung auch als einen einzigen Satz mit zwei infiniten Verben auffassen (das finite Verb bleibt *werden*). Allerdings kann man **nicht** eines der Objekte weglassen, sondern muss beide nennen:

> Ich werde ihn unterstützen und ihm helfen.

Nur wenn beide Pronomen zufällig gleich sind, kann man eines weglassen:

> Ich werde **euch** unterstützen und (*euch*) helfen.

Obiges gilt natürlich uneingeschränkt, wenn die Kasus gleich sind, denn dann *muss* das Pronomen gleich sein; deswegen noch ein anderes Beispiel:

> Ich werde **ihn** aufnehmen und (*ihn*) bewirten.

Comment: Laut Duden (Band 4 sowie 9) müssen bei gleichlautenden Pronomen mit unterschiedlichem Kasus beide Pronomen gesetzt werden.

Comment: @Loong Einer davon ist sicherlich »richtiges und gutes Deutsch« oder? In der Umgangssprache würd ich die Beispiele auf jeden Fall zulassen. Ob ich es auch formal-schriftlich machen würde, müsste ich ausprobieren.

Comment: Ja, Band 4 ist „Die Grammatik“, der leichter verdauliche Band 9 ist „Richtiges und gutes Deutsch“.